# Can compile and link use different compilers when cross-compile?

Tags: gcc, clang, unix-ar

I'd like to know if I can use different compilers for compile and link.

For example ,I have two files ,a.c and b.c,
I use clang to compile a.c and b.c:

```
clang -c a.c -o a.o
clang -c b.c -o b.o
```

and then use gcc to link the two .o file as a so library:

```
gcc -lm -lz -shared a.o b.o -o libad.so
```

I generate the so file successfully,but the app will crash when using this library.

Update:
More detailed information: What I have done is cross-compile , and target platform is armv7a.I use android-NDK and compile the codes on MAC.So the gcc is arm-linux-androideabi-gcc and clang is arm-linux-androideabi-clang.

Comment: Should work. Did you have issues when you tried it?

Comment: I update my questions..

Comment: And it doesn't crash if you use clang to link? That's surprising. But I am afraid debugging this requires access to the code, so you'll have to do it yourself.

Comment: The so is generated successfully,but when it is used, crash will happen..

Comment: But what happens when you link with clang? Does it still crash?

Comment: what I do is cross-compile.There are bugs with the latest android-NDK release when linking with clang.and it will be fixed in the next release...So I just do some other trials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless special flags are specified at link time (`-fuse-ld=xxx`[1][2]), both clang and gcc call the default system linker (which on macOS is `lld` and will probably be `gold` on linux). So running the second statement with either gcc or clang will produce the same linked binary.

[1] https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html

[2] http://clang-developers.42468.n3.nabble.com/LLD-to-be-the-default-linker-in-Clang-td4053949.html